# "Perfect to me" vs. "Perfect for me"

Tags: prepositions, for

Which one is correct?

> 1. You're perfect **for** me.
> 2. You're perfect **to** me.

If both are correct, what is the meaning difference from those two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. You're perfect for me.

This means you are evaluating the relationship, and believe the other person is a perfect match. You go together well, like two peas in a pod (that's an idiom), like two puzzle pieces that fit together.

> 2. You're perfect to me.

You are admiring the other person. Observing them, you say "You are perfect." Like someone looking at a great work of art in a museum, and saying "It's perfect (at least in my opinion)".